# jquery rollover question

Tags: jquery

i made an image roll over (first one i make with out tutorials) and i want to know if there is a way to kill the script if the one image ends with over.jpg and make script continue if the image doesn't

this is my code

```
$('#topNav a img').hover(function(){
    var rSrc = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).attr('src','images/' + rSrc + 'over.jpg');
}, function(){
    var rSrc = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/' + rSrc + '.gif');
});
```

html

```
    <a href="index.html" class="nav"><img src="images/m_1over.jpg" name="m_1"/></a>
<a href="aboutus.html" class="nav"><img src="images/m_2.gif" name="m_2"/></a>
```

i tried adding

```
if($('img[src$=.gif]')
```

before the script but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$('#topNav a img').not("[src$=over.jpg]").hover(function(){ ...
```

See http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: thanks a lot, don't know why i didn't think of this, i've used the .not before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `not()` method like this:

```
$('#topNav a img').not('#topNav a img[src=over.jpg]').hover(function(){...}
```

Comment: What is #top? And the source should *end with* over.jpg, am I missing something here?

Comment: @karim79: That was a typo, updated thanks. As for name, I feel image name is `over.jpg` in all or `src$=over.jpg` or `src*=over.jpg` should work depending on file name.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you need something like this?

```
$('#topNav a img').each(function(i, el) {
   if ($(el).attr('src').match('\\.gif$') == '.gif') 
   {
           $(el).hover(function(){
              var rSrc = $(this).attr('name');
              $(this).attr('src','images/' + rSrc + 'over.jpg');
           }, 
           function(){
              var rSrc = $(this).attr('name');
              $(this).attr('src', 'images/' + rSrc + '.gif');
           });
   }
}
```

You can play with the selector here, where I tested the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/NE3Ps/